# Multiple Docker containers with Avahi daemons

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian, avahi

I'm trying to set up a smart-home Raspberry Pi using Docker to isolate every element of the system. However, two of those Dockers use Avahi to broadcast themselves in the home network - one contains Homebridge, the other Shairport-Sync.

After a lot of struggle I've managed to make Avahi work on one of the following: host OS, Homebridge container OR (actually, xor) Shairport container. However, when more than one daemon is running, only one of them works (the first one launched). The others just loop endlessly with "host name conflict, retrying with HOSTNAME-n", with n approaching infinity.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from trying to advertise twice the same host (the same IP address) from different network interfaces.

When the first container is started, Avahi advertises over mDNS your presence (e.g., "hostname.local. mDNS_IN A 192.168.0.10" and associated _service._x.hostname.local SRV settings).

When the second container is started, a new Avahi advertises over mDNS its presence again. When that happens, the first Avahi will complain about having the hostname/ip address leased. Then, the second Avahi will try a different hostname in case it was due to a hostname collision.

But it was not a hostname collision, it was an IP collision. You would need to have different IP interfaces on each service in order for this to work.
That is, assign multiple IPs to your raspberry on different virtual interfaces of eth0, and then bind each virtual interface to a different container (and use different hostnames for each docker service).

You will need to have multiple IPs available on your subnetwork for the Raspberry Pi in order for this to work.

If your intent is to only use the interfaces to broadcast the services (and not browse for other mDNS services), you can add an iptables rule forbidding multicast traffic between your own interfaces.